# How to calculate md5 Checksum matching gsutil algorithm

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Using Google's `gsutil` command line tool I can generate a file's `md5Checksum` value by running:

```
gsutil hash -h c:/folder/filename.ext
```

The resulting `md5Checksum` value would look like:

```
abf688a738aedee31a1e5462e7a1a650
```

I wonder if there is a way to generate the same `md5Checksum` value using one of the Python's modules such as `checksum` module for example.

I have tried to use:

```
import hashlib
hashlib.md5(open(full_path, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
```

but the resulting 'md5Checksum' value is not the same as the one `gsutil hash -h full_path` generates.

Comment: I get the exact same result using `gsutil hash -h` and `hashlib.md5(...).hexdigest()` on a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gsutil` uses the standard MD5 generator.

It can run in one of two modes - printing out the hexadecimal version of the MD5 hash, or the base64 version.

The instructions for the tool:

```
NAME
  hash - Calculate file hashes


SYNOPSIS

  gsutil hash [-c] [-h] [-m] filename...



DESCRIPTION
  The hash command calculates hashes on a local file that can be used to compare
  with gsutil ls -L output. If a specific hash option is not provided, this
  command calculates all gsutil-supported hashes for the file.

  Note that gsutil automatically performs hash validation when uploading or
  downloading files, so this command is only needed if you want to write a
  script that separately checks the hash for some reason.

  If you calculate a CRC32c hash for the file without a precompiled crcmod
  installation, hashing will be very slow. See "gsutil help crcmod" for details.

OPTIONS
  -c          Calculate a CRC32c hash for the file.

  -h          Output hashes in hex format. By default, gsutil uses base64.

  -m          Calculate a MD5 hash for the file.
```

So by doing `gsutil hash -h`, you want `gsutil` to generate what Python would generate if you used the `hexdigest()` as you are doing.

### Working example

Let's create a baseline, here's a random image I just uploaded.

### [image: Why not zoiderg?]

If you save that to you system, and run `gsutil hash -h`, here's what you should see:

```
gsutil hash -h ~/Downloads/TPQgK.png
Hashes [hex] for /Users/birryree/Downloads/TPQgK.png:
    Hash (crc32c):      CE24CAD6
    Hash (md5):     71c02116024d9fbd04663f4b9c0a082c
```

In Python, you can generate the hash with what you already had.

```
import hashlib
hashlib.md5(open('/Users/birryree/Downloads/TPQgK.png', 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
# output: 71c02116024d9fbd04663f4b9c0a082c
```

Alternatively, if you don't use the `-h` flag, it will generate the hash in Base64 encoding.

```
gsutil hash /Users/birryree/Downloads/TPQgK.png
Hashes [base64] for /Users/birryree/Downloads/TPQgK.png:
    Hash (crc32c):      ziTK1g==
    Hash (md5):     ccAhFgJNn70EZj9LnAoILA==
```

And you can generate it like so

```
import hashlib
hashlib.md5(open('/Users/birryree/Downloads/TPQgK.png', 'rb').read()).digest().encode('base64').strip()
# Out[6]: 'ccAhFgJNn70EZj9LnAoILA=='
```

Comment: Is there a way to get as output only value of hash?
Let's say I want to compare md5 hash value from remote gsutil hash -m gs://[object_name]
  with some value - I have to parse string 
Hashes [base64] for object_name:
    Hash (crc32c):      ziTK1g==
    Hash (md5):     ccAhFgJNn70EZj9LnAoILA==

With some regex. What is not convenient and not reliable due to output format can be changed. Is there a way get directly ccAhFgJNn70EZj9LnAoILA==?

Comment: @EvgenyGerbut Not that I can see - there are no options to format `gsutil hash` output. You can work on the assumption the hash is always last in the output, regardless of other text, so...a way to do this is to have it output the hash type you want and then run something like:  `gsutil -q hash -m OBJECT_PATH | tr -d '\n\t' | rev | cut -d':' -f 1 | rev` which will output the final hash. Or, since I assume you have Python, you can pass the output to Python: `gsutil -q hash -m OBJECT_PATH | python -c "import sys; print(''.join(list(sys.stdin)).split(':')[-1].strip())"`.